# Adding a footer with text on left and right side in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have added the following code to my `footer.php` file in my wordpress website (using twentyfourteen theme). The Privacy policy and terms and conditions, with their respective links, are shown on the left side, but my text about copyright is not shown on the right side (it is not shown anywhere). Anyone knows what I missed?

```html
<div class="MainDiv">
  <div class="MainBottom footer">
    <div class="MainFooter container">
      <div class="LeftSide ">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.myurl.html">Privacy Policy</a>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.myurl.html">Terms and Conditions</a>

        <div class="RightSide">
          Copyright © 2018 My Company. <span>All rights reserved.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="BottomFix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: First of all, some of your `divs` aren't closed. Not that it'd matter (the browser would still parse it), but I think it aids in your confusion. 

From the structure you've created, it appears as if the `.RightSide` <div> is nested under the `.LeftSide` <div>, making it a child element. I'm guessing that's not what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`for the `.MainFooter` container, and to fix that at the bottom of the window, you can use `position: fixed` for `MainBottom` (plus some other settings - see below).

BTW: You forgot to close the `.LeftSide` DIV, i also added that in my snippet.

```css
.MainBottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.MainFooter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainDiv">
  <div class="MainBottom footer">
    <div class="MainFooter container">
      <div class="LeftSide ">
        <a target="blank" href="https://www.myurl.html">Privacy Policy</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a target="blank" href="https://www.myurl.html">Terms and Conditions</a>
      </div>
      <div class="RightSide">Copyright © 2018 My Company. <span>All rights reserved.</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically div has alignment to the left side. It displays as you can see in the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what styles you've written for those classes, but here is a slightly modified version of your initial code with a simple flexbox-style fix:

```css
.MainFooter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainDiv">
  <div class="MainBottom footer">
    <div class="MainFooter container">
      <div class="LeftSide ">
        <a target="blank" href="https://www.myurl.html">Privacy Policy</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a target="blank" href="https://www.myurl.html">Terms and Conditions</a>
      </div>
      <div class="RightSide">
        Copyright © 2018 My Company. <span>All rights reserved.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="BottomFix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```